# How can I use jQuery to display the title of a photo from Flickr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

I made a search event handler in my HTML which takes the input and makes the search request to flickr's photo.search by appending the value after "&text=" to search by text. This then displays 7 relevant photos to the search term.
I've added a click event handler to then insert the details to my HTML file to display in a modal when the user clicks on a photo and then display the photo by setting the modal css to display. The issue comes when I try to display the photo's title under the image.

Search button event handler:

```
//search button function
function searchButton_handler(){
    let input = $("#textInput").val();
    let htmlStr = "";
    $.get(SEARCH_REQ + "&text=" + input, function(data){

        nrequest = data.photos.photo.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < data.photos.photo.length; i++){
            let photoID = data.photos.photo[i].id;
            let photoTitle = data.photos.photo[i].title;
            let photoObj = {"file": photoID, "title": photoTitle};
            search_photos.push(photoObj);
        
            getSizes(photoObj, photoID, photoTitle);
        }
    });

}
```

Get sizes from flickr:

```
//access getSizes array from flickr
function getSizes(photoObj, photoID){
    let getSizeReq = GETSIZES_REQ + photoID;
    $.get(getSizeReq, function(data){
        let photoURL = data.sizes.size[2].source;
        photoObj.full = data.sizes.size[data.sizes.size.length-3].source;
        photoObj.file = photoURL;
        
        display_search(search_photos);
    });
}
```

Display search results:

```
//display photos returned from search
function display_search(search_photos){
    let htmlStr = "";
    
    for (let i = 0; i < search_photos.length; i++){
        htmlStr += `<figure data-full="${search_photos[i].full}"><img src="${search_photos[i].file}" alt="${search_photos[i].title}" width="150" height="150"><figcaption>${search_photos[i].title}</figcaption></figure>`;
        
    }
    
    $("#item2").html(htmlStr);
   
    $('figure').each(function(index){
        $(this).click(function(){
            
            $("#modal-container").css("display", "block");
            $("#modal-content").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-full"));
        })
    });
}
```

Can somebody help me? I've tried everything I could think of and console logging it either returns undefined or an error. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post images of your code but post the actual code itself. Edit your question and insert your code.

Comment: Did you try: `$("#modal-caption").text($(this).find("figcaption").text())`  where modal-caption would the div where you want your text